# Create table using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have a task. Task is to allow user to create table in database. User inputs columns names and types, so we do not know how many columns will be in our table. 
The problem is: I must use Entity Framework. Can i do it using entity framework? Or it is not possible?

Comment: No it is not possible. That is NOT what an ORM is designed for. An ORM is for defining mappings from the database and classes (which are defined at compile time). For this to work your user must be able to define classes...at run time...

Comment: Thank you. I thought so too. But teacher gave me that task

Comment: You could in theory do this using generic classes to build the structure of your tables at runtime and then invoke the migrations utility shipped with the Entity Framework during runtime from within your application. http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/ef-code-first-migrations-update-database-outside-of-visual-studio/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: @DanielLane generic against what class?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this isn't the best approach, but you can send to your database a query containing your CREATE TABLE definition.

For example:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myTableDefinition = "CREATE TABLE TEST(COLUMNTESTE INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)";
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(myTableDefinition);
        }
    }
}
```

Final result:

[image]